# How do I get the width of the label text of a button?

Tags: button, width, livecode

How can I set the width of a button created in a script to the one of its label text?

```
on createButtonWithLabel aLabel
   create button
   set the label of it to aLabel
   -- set the width of the button to the space used by 'aLabel'
   -- ??
end createButtonWithLabel
```

searching for *width* in the LiveCode dictionary brings up more than a dozen entries but nothing seems to apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

set the width of button "yourButton" to the formattedWidth of button "yourButton"

Craig Newman